# Calling Spring Rest service from c++ or Ruby

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am learning Spring Rest services, I have question regarding Spring rest services

Is it possible to call Spring Rest service from other language like c++ or Ruby, where c++ or Ruby will act as Client and Spring Rest service as service or resource provider.

If it's possible can some one explain simple, detailed manner with example.

The reason of asking the question, if we develop a web service using Jax-ws, the interoperability will happen across the technologies like calling  Java based web service  calling from C++ or and vice versa, can same thing happen using Rest service which is developed in Spring Rest or using Jersey api framework.

Answer (score 0):

A REST call is just an http call. The service doesn't care what language the client is coded in - could be a browser, a mobile phone, written in c++, java, c, objective-c, it doesn't matter.

Typically if you have object data to pass from the client to the service, you would encode it in JSON or XML.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. The key of course is Serializing/Deserializing Data. As long as your Rest service accepts serialized data as input, and returns serialized data as output.

For Example, lets say you have an endpoint http://www.example.com/public-api/foo, with acceptable method GET (it provides data).

In Spring, you have a resource named Foo.java, that takes the following form

```
class Foo implements Serializable {
     private static long serialVersionUID = -1L;

     private String someProperty;

     public Foo() {
         ...
     }

     public String getSomeProperty() { 
         return this.someProperty; 
     }

     public void setSomeProperty(String someProperty) {
         this.someProperty = someProperty;
     }

}
```

With the following Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value={"/"})
class FooController {

    @RequestMapping(value={"/foo"}, method={RequestMethod.GET})
    public HttpEntity<Foo> foo() {


        ...

        Foo foo = new Foo();

        ...

        return new ResponseEntity<ResourceSupport>(foo, HttpStatus.OK);

    }


}
```

When you access this in your browser, it will return the following text

```
{
   "_self": "http://www.example.com/public-api/foo",
   "someProperty": ...
}
```

This output (in JSON), can be parsed in Ruby and C++ (or any language really) quite simply.

Inputting is the same way. Instead of parsing JSON, you would just POST or PUT JSON data that conforms to whatever resource you're trying to input. To POST or PUT a new Foo object, you just POST or PUT JSON data with the appropriate Properties.